# Dart internal constructor

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having weird runtime error during execution of my Widget's constructor.

Here is the class:

```
class NumberPicker extends StatefulWidget {

  NumberPicker.integer({
    Key key,
    @required int initialValue,
    @required int minValue,
    @required int maxValue,
  })
      : assert(initialValue != null),
        assert(minValue != null),
        assert(maxValue != null),
        assert(maxValue > minValue),
        assert(initialValue >= minValue &&
            initialValue <= maxValue),
        this._internal(
          minDoubleValue: -1.0,
          maxDoubleValue: -1.0,
          initialDoubleValue: -1.0,
          decimalPlaces: 0,
          minIntValue: minValue,
          maxIntValue: maxValue,
          initialIntValue: initialValue
      );


  NumberPicker._internal({
    Key key,
    @required this.minDoubleValue,
    @required this.maxDoubleValue,
    @required this.initialDoubleValue,
    @required this.decimalPlaces,
    @required this.minIntValue,
    @required this.maxIntValue,
    @required this.initialIntValue,
  }) :
        super(key: key);


  final double minDoubleValue;
  final double maxDoubleValue;
  final double initialDoubleValue;
  final int decimalPlaces;
  final int minIntValue;
  final int maxIntValue;
  final int initialIntValue;

  @override
  _NumberPickerState createState() => new _NumberPickerState();
}
```

When I call `new NumberPicker.integer(initialValue: 50, minValue: 1, maxValue: 100)`

I get following error:

```
I/flutter ( 3873): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3873): The following _CompileTimeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 3873): 'package:numberpicker/numberpicker.dart': error: line 20: '=' expected
I/flutter ( 3873):   this._internal(
I/flutter ( 3873):                 ^
```

What is worth mentioning is that code compiles and I have no errors about syntax but when I invoke the constructor only thing I see is stacktrace :(

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you remove the asserts it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call an other constructor of your class, you should use a factory constructor on `NumberPicker.integer`, but I don't know why you don't get any error from the analyzer, maybe you should fill a bug.

```
factory NumberPicker.integer({
  Key key,
  @required int initialValue,
  @required int minValue,
  @required int maxValue,
}) {
  assert(initialValue != null);
  assert(minValue != null);
  assert(maxValue != null);
  assert(maxValue > minValue);
  assert(initialValue >= minValue && initialValue <= maxValue);

  return new NumberPicker._internal(
      minDoubleValue: -1.0,
      maxDoubleValue: -1.0,
      initialDoubleValue: -1.0,
      decimalPlaces: 0,
      minIntValue: minValue,
      maxIntValue: maxValue,
      initialIntValue: initialValue
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have asserts in your initializer list, only fields assignment. 
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/71eab37e91c7d94e2dbcf7817def32d5
works fine.

Comment: Yes, you can by adding enableAssertInitializer: true to analysis_options.yaml

Answer (score 0):

this is not accessible instead of `this._internal` use `NumberPicker._internal`, 'new' keyword not longer necessary in flutter.